# Airline changes flight schedule 6 weeks in advance: are they still obligated to reimburse me if I change to a different airline for the original date?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, passenger-rights, schedule-change

I already found a lot of information online but unfortunately no clear answer to my specific question.

**My situation and option number 1:**

I was supposed to fly for 1 week, end of September. However, the airline changed the flight schedule and offered me a new flight schedule, also end of September, where the flights are only 4 days apart. That option is not acceptable to me.

**Option number 2:**

They also offered me to rebook my flight. I would be okay with rebooking to flights 1 week apart in the beginning of September which are available according to their website. However, I'm only "allowed" to rebook to flights within 14 days of the original dates, so this doesn't seem to work either.

**Option number 3:**

I also have the option to get a refund. However, I booked those flights really early to save money and if I compare prices now for flights with other airlines in September, they're very expensive compared to what I originally paid for my flights. So the refund money doesn't even come close to what I'd have to pay to book new flights now.

So what do I do? Can I make my airline reimburse me for a rebooking to another airline? Or am I just out of luck and I have to accept a change of my flight schedule from 1 week to 4 days? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

The flight is by WizzAir from EU to non-EU and back.

Answer (score 7):

All of this depends A LOT on the airline and countries involved but by and large the options that you listed are fairly "normal" and "complete"

> Can I make my airline reimburse me for a rebooking to another airline?

No. Not even EU 261 will support that if they change with a 6 weeks notice.

> Or am I just out of luck

Mostly yes.

> I have to accept a change of my flight schedule from 1 week to 4 days?

Not necessarily. You can choose to get a refund and not fly at all or postpone your flight to a "cheaper" time.

For the full terms of Whiz Air see section 6.3 in https://wizzair.com/static/docs/default-source/downloadable-documents/general-conditions-of-carriage/gcc-wuk/wam-wuk-final-compare_72e26162.pdf

Comment: Hmm, am I overlooking something? So the airline can basically screw my schedule for free without repercussions but on the other hand, if I'd want to rebook or cancel my flight then I'll have to pay a fee? Seems a little unfair.

Comment: Obviously thank you very much for giving me feedback. :) I don't want to seem ungrateful. I'm just looking for more information if I'm mistaking something. And most importantly: what to learn from this for my future bookings - how to protect myself better. :/

Comment: @CannedMeatLover You've got two options in future, choose an airline with a more frequent schedule to your destination (or one that is part of an alliance with other airlines that do) or book a package holiday (they are much less likely to cancel a flight because they almost always fill up a plane). If you're that price sensitive I would personally call the whole thing off if you can, hopefully you can get a full refund for your hotel.

Comment: @CannedMeatLover They're really not "free to screw your schedule". Any significant change they make automatically gives you a right to a full refund,so you get all your money back and are free to make alternative arrangements as you see fit. That's exactly what you would have to do,had they changed the schedule before you booked.

Comment: "Not even EU 261 will support that if they change with a 6 weeks notice" - may I ask for a source for this? EC261 article 8.1 provides that the passenger is entitled to be re-routing, under comparable transport conditions "at the earliest opportunity" (b) OR later (c). I see nothing there about exceptions for sufficient notice.